# feathers-blob error dauria can no read property startsWith

Tags: feathersjs

I just started using feathers-blob for uploading files from a angular4 client using dropzone.
I followed the example but made an explicit service for the upload not tu blur up the app.js.
It compiles without error, but on execution i receive the following error, even i do NOT use multipart portion:

Info: error:

> system/file-upload - Method: create: Cannot read property 'startsWith'
>   of undefined error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of
>   undefined
>       at Dauria.parseDataURI (/projects/esaas-2/esaas-server-basic/node_modules/feathers-blob/node_modules/dauria/dauria.js:27:17)
>       at Object.create (/projects/esaas-2/esaas-server-basic/node_modules/feathers-blob/lib/index.js:87:52)
>       at /projects/esaas-2/esaas-server-basic/node_modules/feathers-hooks/lib/hooks.js:101:31
>       at /projects/esaas-2/esaas-server-basic/node_modules/feathers-hooks/lib/hooks.js:85:16

I also made sure to use the same versions of feathers-blob and dauria and multer as in the sample and not the newer ones from the npm. Result is the same.
What am i doing wrong? Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look into `dauria`'s code you'll see where the problem comes from:

```
Dauria.prototype.parseDataURI = function(dataURI){
 if(!( dataURI.startsWith('data:') )) throw new Error(
   this.errors.MISSING_PREFIX
 );
```

Which means that somehow the value that you pass to the caller `dauria.parseDataURI(yourDataVariable)` - the `yourDataVariable` value does *not* start with `'data:'`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test on Node and I had the same error while trying to upload an image. I solved it by adding the string "data:image/jpeg;base64" followed by the 64 encoded image.